# parsing xml content in python

Tags: python, xml

I want to write information from xml to dict in Python.
Below is xml file:

```
<data>
  <files>
    <links>
      <item>
        <file_name>file1</file_name>
        <id>100</id>
      </item>
      <item>
        <file_name>file2</file_name>
        <id>200</id>
      </item>
      <item>
        <file_name>file3</file_name>
        <id>300</id>
      </item>
    </links>
  </files>
</data>
```

To Python dict like a:

```
xml_content = { 'file1' = 100, 'file2' = 200, 'file3' = 300 }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) this simple code can be used to extract your dictionary:

install `xmltodict` with `pip install xmltodict`

```
import xmltodict

doc = xmltodict.parse("""
<data>
  <files>
    <links>
      <item>
        <file_name>file1</file_name>
        <id>100</id>
      </item>
      <item>
        <file_name>file2</file_name>
        <id>200</id>
      </item>
      <item>
        <file_name>file3</file_name>
        <id>300</id>
      </item>
    </links>
  </files>
</data>
""")

d = {}

for item in doc["data"]["files"]["links"]["item"]:
    d[item["file_name"]] = int(item["id"])

print(d)
```

`d` will be:

```
{u'file3': 300, u'file2': 200, u'file1': 100}
```

Alternatively you can load the xml from a file like this:

```
with open('path/to/file.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
```

Comment: I recieve that message:
>>> for item in doc["data"]["files"]["links"]["item"]:
...     d[item["file_name"]] = int(item["id"])
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: 'file_name'

Comment: @dracons2 This happens because in your xml file the `<file_name>` either does not exist or has another name. But my answer is correct for your question and if your file is built as you specified the example will work.

Comment: TRUE, The example works properly. Thank for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup should help you

Link - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Something like this should work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<data>
  <files>
    <links>
      <item>
        <file_name>file1</file_name>
        <id>100</id>
      </item>
      <item>
        <file_name>file2</file_name>
        <id>200</id>
      </item>
      <item>
        <file_name>file3</file_name>
        <id>300</id>
      </item>
    </links>
  </files>
</data>
""")


xml_content = { item.find('file_name').string: item.find('id').string for item in soup.find_all('item') }
```

Output:

```
{'file2': '200', 'file3': '300', 'file1': '100'}
```